# Why don't these integrals give the same result?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The following illustrates my attempt to compute the area common to $f(\theta)=2(1+cos(\theta))$  and $g(\theta)=2(1-cos(\theta))$ by 2 methods of polar integration. In the first column I compute the indefinite integral of $1/2\int^{\pi/2}_0{f^2(\theta)}+1/2\int^{\pi/2}_0{g^2(\theta)}$. In the second column I compute the indefinite integral of $1/2\int^{\pi/2}_0{g^2(\theta)}$ and eveluate it from $0$ to $\pi/2$. In the third column I evaluate $$1/2\int^{\pi/2}_0{f^2(\theta)}+1/2\int^{\pi/2}_0{g^2(\theta)}$$ but get an unexpected result.

More generally, am I safe in assuming that $\int^a_b{f(\theta)+g(\theta)}$=$\int^a_b{f(\theta)}+\int^a_b{g(\theta)}$ so long as both $\int^a_b{f(\theta)}$ and $\int^a_b{g(\theta)}$ are positive?

[image]

Comment: How did $\pi$ disappear in your second column?

Comment: Sorry, come again?

Comment: I mean, it doesn't disappear, as far as I can tell

Comment: Let me be more explicit: are you sure you did the substitution in the penultimate line of the second column correctly? There should be a $\pi$ in the result if you did things right.

Comment: Yea OK sorry, I see what you mean and will update the image shortly. But the solutions are still different. Thank you very much for your help so far, tho.

Comment: To get the green area in column 3 you need to evaluate $1/2\int^{\pi/2}_0{f^2(\theta)}+1/2\int^{\pi}_{\pi/2}{g^2(\theta)} $